# Prime Factors (32 bits, without Sieve)

Tags: c, primes, factors

I wrote this prime factors program as a programming exercise.

Any comments or constructive criticisms are welcome.

One question: prime[] is an array which stores the number's prime factors and associated exponents. How many elements, at most, does this array require? That is, what is the greatest number of prime factors needed to express any number between 1 and 4294967295? As an example 750 would need 3 elements since 750 = 2 * 3 * 5 ^ 3. I could do an exhaustive test using a static variable to keep track of the maximum value of pIndex but the 2.4 billion numbers would take at least 12 hours on my single core machine. Is there a quicker way to determine the answer?

```
/* primeexponents.c

   display a number's prime factors using exponents and also its number of
   divisors

   note: unsigned 32 bit numbers (1 - 4294967295)
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void primeExponents (unsigned long int number, unsigned int list[])
{
    printf ("\nnumber = %lu\n", number);

    struct
    {
        unsigned long int factor;
        int exponent;
    } prime[20] = { { 0, 0 } };

    unsigned long int num = number;
    int pIndex = 0, lIndex = 0;

    prime[pIndex].factor = (unsigned long int) list[lIndex];

    while ( prime[pIndex].factor <= num / prime[pIndex].factor ) {
        if ( num % prime[pIndex].factor == 0 ) {
            ++prime[pIndex].exponent;
            num /= prime[pIndex].factor;
        }
        else {
            if ( prime[pIndex].exponent > 0 ) 
                ++pIndex;
            ++lIndex;
            prime[pIndex].factor = (unsigned long int) list[lIndex];
        }
    }

    // num = greatest prime factor

    if ( num == prime[pIndex].factor )
        ++prime[pIndex].exponent;
    else {
        if ( prime[pIndex].exponent > 0 )
            ++pIndex;
        prime[pIndex].factor = num;
        prime[pIndex].exponent = 1;
    }

    printf ("prime factors =");

    unsigned long int product = 1;
    int divisors = 1;

    for ( int i = 0; i <= pIndex; ++i ) {
        printf (" %lu", prime[i].factor);
        if ( prime[i].exponent > 1 )   
            printf (" ^ %i", prime[i].exponent);
        if ( i < pIndex )
            printf (" *");
        // calculate product of prime factors to verify result
        for ( int j = 1; j <= prime[i].exponent; ++j )
            product *= prime[i].factor;
        // calculate number of divisors
        divisors *= prime[i].exponent + 1;
    }
    printf ("\n");

    printf ("product of prime factors = %lu", product);
    if ( product != number )
        printf (" <<< error >>>");
    printf ("\n");

    printf ("divisors = %i\n\n", divisors);
}

void generateList (unsigned int list[])
{
    // generate a list of prime numbers to use as trial factors, i.e.
    // list[0] = 2, [1] = 3, [2] = 5, [3] = 7, [4] = 11, ... [6541] = 65521

    bool isPrime;
    list[0] = 2;
    list[1] = 3;
    int index = 2;

    for ( unsigned int i = 5; i <= 65535; i += 2 ) {
        isPrime = true;

        for ( int j = 1; (i / list[j] >= list[j]) && isPrime; ++j ) {
            if ( i % list[j] == 0 ) 
                isPrime = false;
        }

        if ( isPrime ) {
            list[index] = i;
            ++index;
        }    
    }        
}

int main (void)
{
    printf ("\nPrime Factors with Exponents Program\n\n");

    unsigned int list[6542];

    generateList (list);

    unsigned long int number;

    do {
        printf ("enter a number (from 1 to 4294967295, 0 to exit): ");
        scanf ("%lu", &number);

        if ( number != 0 )
            primeExponents (number, list);
    }
    while ( number != 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an exhaustive search: \$2*3*5*7*11*13*17*19*23*29 = 6469693230 > 2^{32}\$, so it is safe to allocate 9 slots.

---

`primeExponents` does too much and shall be split into three functions, one to factorize a number, another to validate factorization, and yet another to print it.

---

The factorization logic is extremely hard to follow. Consider instead

```
void factorize(int num, factors_t * factors, int * primes)
{ 
  for (; num > 1; ++primes) {
    factors->prime = *primes;
    factors.exponent = 0;

    while (num % *primes == 0) {
      factors->exponent++;
      num /= **primes; // Edit: shame on me.
    }

    if (factors->exponent > 0) {
      factors++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution as to the maximum size for the array was what I had originally thought -- I didn't mention it so as to not bias an answer. Thanks.

Comment: What causes `for (; num > 1; ++primes) {` to end?  `num` is never changed and there are no `break/return`.

Comment: @chux I think there's an implied (unstated) division statement in the while loop of vnp's remarkably concise code.

Comment: @chux See edit. Shame on me.

Comment: Perhaps `num /= *primes;` instead of `num /= **primes;`?  Minor: also the closer `num /= *primes;` is to `num % *primes`, I _suspect_ the more likely a compiler will use an optimization to effectively code these operations together as one div/rem.

Comment: @ringzero Yes its concise and lacks code.  Aside from the formerly missing division,  the calling function lacks knowledge of now  many `factor[]` were used.  I'd expect a count in `factors_t`or the return value - making the code less concise. Had the signature been `void factorize(int num, factors_t * restrict factors, const int * restrict primes)`, a compiler can employ more optimizations -  making the code less concise.  SE has a great place for [concise code](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com). I prefer fully functional code that also handles/documents edge cases. (0,1, neg, missing here.)

Comment: @ringzero It is a good answer, yet this used concise types of `int` rather than your `unsigned long`, subtly improving the tightness of code, yet with reduced functional range (2-0x7fff or 2-0x7fff_ffff), unlike the posted required 1 - 4294967295.  Still a good answer and more concise than the post --> UV, remarkable - not yet.